# Problema con Bucle For y Medias

Tags: java

me ha surgido un problema al hacer un ejercicio que solicite al usuario el número de valores de temperaturas tomadas (debe ser mayor que
0) y luego pida las temperaturas y devuelva el número de veces que ésta tiene un valor inferior a cero grados y la temperatura media.
Actualmente lo he hecho asi: (Declare todas las variables como Int).

```
System.out.println("Introduzca el numero de temperaturas(POSITIVOS)");
temperaturas = entrada.nextInt();
do
{
for (ntemperaturas = 1; ntemperaturas <= temperaturas ; ntemperaturas++)
{
System.out.println("Temperatura numero " + ntemperaturas + ":" );
temperatura = entrada.nextInt();
}
}
while (temperaturas>0);
```

Me gustaria saber en que me equivoco y como corregirlo para llegar a completar el enunciado de arriba.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: por favor cambia la etiqueta JavaScript por la de Java pues no son lo mismo y tu estas usando el último

Comment: @shadow ya que usted editó la pregunta, podría haber cambiado de etiquetas.

Comment: @Xam no, yo solo le di formato al código pero la etiqueta indica confusión en el OP por eso no le hice el cambio y se lo comenté nada mas

Answer (score 0):

La condición del **While** siempre va a ser verdadera, por tal razón nunca va a salir del bucle, osea estas creando un bucle infinito. Una de las soluciones posibles es eliminar el for, pues es innecesario y cada vez que estes recorriendo cada temperatura disminuyas en uno las temperaturas y tambien creando un iterador, algo asi:

```
System.out.println("Introduzca el numero de temperaturas(POSITIVOS)");
temperaturas = entrada.nextInt();
int i = 0;
do{

    System.out.println("Temperatura numero " + i + ":" );
    int temperatura = entrada.nextInt();
    System.out.println("La temperatura: " + i + " es: " + temperatura);
    i++;

}while (i < temperaturas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes programar según tu enunciado, veamos:

1. "Solicite al usuario el número de valores de temperaturas tomadas (debe ser mayor que 0)":

R: Aquí debes solicitar el número de temperaturas que registrará e inmediatamente validar si es mayor a 0 para continuar `(total = entrada.nextInt()) (if(total > 0))`

2. "luego pida las temperaturas":

R: Aquí debes leer lo que el usuario ingresa `(tempeatura = entrada.nextInt())`.

3. "devuelva el número de veces que ésta tiene un valor inferior a cero grados"

R: Para poder devolver el número de veces tenemos que crear un contador que verifique `(if(temperatura < 0) contador_bajo_cero++)`

4. "la temperatura media"

R: Para poder calcular un promedio necesitas un contador y un acumulador. Luego dividir el acumulador entre el contador. `(acumulador += temperatura) (contador++) (acumulador /contador)`

```
System.out.println("Introduzca el numero de temperaturas(POSITIVOS)");
int total = entrada.nextInt();
int contador_bajo_cero = 0;
int contador = 0;
double acumulador = 0;

if(total > 0)
{
    for(int i=1; i<= total; i++)
    {
        double temperatura = entrada.nextInt();     
        if(temperatura < 0)
            contador_bajo_cero++;

        acumulador += temperatura;
        contador++;
    }

    System.out.println("Se encontraron " + contador_bajo_cero + " valores inferiores a 0 grados.");
    System.out.println("La temperatura media es " + (acumulador/contador));
}
else
    System.out.println("No introdujo numero mayor a 0");
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!!! tene en cuenta que esta pregunta tiene casi 6 meses, por lo que es probable que este abandonada, ademas de ser un ejercicio. como referencia, podrias hacer el [tour]. Gracias